# Error of qmake building Qt app image with Yocto

Tags: yocto, yocto-layer

this is my first time when I use Yocto and I want to create an image for Raspberry Pi 4 of a Qt Qml application, but I got the following error :

> ERROR: mytest1-0.1-r0 do_configure: Error calling
> /home/dragos/workspace/poky/build/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-poky-linux-gnueabi/mytest1/0.1-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/qmake -makefile -o Makefile  -r   /home/dragos/workspace/poky/build/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-poky-linux-gnueabi/mytest1/0.1-r0/untitled.pro
> --  ERROR: mytest1-0.1-r0 do_configure: Execution of '/home/dragos/workspace/poky/build/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-poky-linux-gnueabi/mytest1/0.1-r0/temp/run.do_configure.72533'
> failed with exit code 1 ERROR: Logfile of failure stored in:
> /home/dragos/workspace/poky/build/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-poky-linux-gnueabi/mytest1/0.1-r0/temp/log.do_configure.72533

[This is the build configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ue9Z2.png)

[Version of qmake and Qt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7vDfz.png)

And I tried to run locally using that qmake and i got this:

Should I change the version of Qt to and older version like 5.12 or the problem is another one?

This is following warnings of the errors:

> Log data follows: | DEBUG: Executing shell function
> qmake5_base_preconfigure | DEBUG: Shell function
> qmake5_base_preconfigure finished | DEBUG: Executing shell function
> do_configure | Project ERROR: Unknown module(s) in QT: quick | ERROR:
> Error calling
> /home/dragos/workspace/poky/build/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-poky-linux-gnueabi/mytest1/0.1-r0/recipe-sysroot-native/usr/bin/qmake -makefile -o Makefile  -r   /home/dragos/workspace/poky/build/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-poky-linux-gnueabi/mytest1/0.1-r0/untitled.pro
> -- | WARNING: exit code 1 from a shell command. | ERROR: Execution of '/home/dragos/workspace/poky/build/tmp/work/cortexa7t2hf-neon-vfpv4-poky-linux-gnueabi/mytest1/0.1-r0/temp/run.do_configure.78253'
> failed with exit code 1 ERROR: Task
> (/home/dragos/workspace/poky/meta-test1/recipes-test1/mytest1/mytest1_0.1.bb:do_configure)
> failed with exit code '1'

And this is my .bb file:

```
SUMMARY = "This is my test app"
DESCRIPTION = "Test for qml app"
LICENSE = "CLOSED"


SRC_URI = "file://direction.png \
           file://main.cpp \
           file://main.qml \
           file://qml.qrc \
           file://untitled.pro \
       "
      
S = "${WORKDIR}"

inherit qmake5

do_install_append() {
    echo "installing"
    install -d ${D}${bindir}
    install -m 0755 ${S}/myapp ${D}${bindir}
    install -d ${D}${datadir}/myapp
    install -m 0644 ${S}/qml/* ${D}${datadir}/myapp
}

DEPENDS += "qtbase"
RDEPENDS_${PN} += "qtwayland"

FILES_${PN} += "${bindir}/myapp \
                ${datadir}/myapp/*"
```

main.cpp file

```
    #include <QGuiApplication>
#include <QQmlApplicationEngine>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);

    QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

    QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
    const QUrl url(QStringLiteral("qrc:/main.qml"));
    QObject::connect(&engine, &QQmlApplicationEngine::objectCreated,
                     &app, [url](QObject *obj, const QUrl &objUrl) {
        if (!obj && url == objUrl)
            QCoreApplication::exit(-1);
    }, Qt::QueuedConnection);
    engine.load(url);

    return app.exec();
}
```

main.qml file

```
    import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    color: "#452896"
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    property var vl: 0

    Rectangle{
        width: 200
        height: 200*vl
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        color: "red"
        Behavior on height {
            NumberAnimation{
                duration: 1000
                easing.type: "Linear"
            }
        }
    }

    Timer{
        interval: 1000
        repeat: true
        running: true
        onTriggered: {
            vl = Math.random(100)
            console.log(vl)
        }
    }

    Image {
        id: img
        source: "direction.png"
        width: 40
        height: 40
    }
}
```

qml.qrc file

```
<RCC>
    <qresource prefix="/">
        <file>main.qml</file>
        <file>direction.png</file>
    </qresource>
</RCC>
```

untitled.pro file

```
    QT += quick

CONFIG += c++11

# The following define makes your compiler emit warnings if you use
# any Qt feature that has been marked deprecated (the exact warnings
# depend on your compiler). Refer to the documentation for the
# deprecated API to know how to port your code away from it.
DEFINES += QT_DEPRECATED_WARNINGS

# You can also make your code fail to compile if it uses deprecated APIs.
# In order to do so, uncomment the following line.
# You can also select to disable deprecated APIs only up to a certain version of Qt.
#DEFINES += QT_DISABLE_DEPRECATED_BEFORE=0x060000    # disables all the APIs deprecated before Qt 6.0.0

SOURCES += \
        main.cpp

RESOURCES += qml.qrc

QML_INSTALL_DIR = /qml    

# Additional import path used to resolve QML modules in Qt Creator's code model
QML_IMPORT_PATH = /qml

# Additional import path used to resolve QML modules just for Qt Quick Designer
QML_DESIGNER_IMPORT_PATH =

# Default rules for deployment.
qnx: target.path = /tmp/$${TARGET}/bin
else: unix:!android: target.path = /opt/$${TARGET}/bin
!isEmpty(target.path): INSTALLS += target
```

Suplimentary lines added in local.conf:

```
MACHINE = "raspberrypi4"

DISTRO = "poky"

IMAGE_INSTALL_append += " mytest1 "

DISTRO_FEATURES_append += " wayland "
IMAGE_INSTALL_append += "qtbase qtwayland qtbase-dev qtbase-mkspecs qtbase-tools"
CORE_IMAGE_EXTRA_INSTALL += "wayland weston "
IMAGE_INSTALL += "tslib"


ENABLE_UART = "1"
```

Comment: Can you share your source codes ? I want to reproduce the issue to speed up the help.

Comment: @TalelBELHADJSALEM , thank you. I share the source codes as edit at my question.